# Elastic search updates randomly failing with total=0 successful=0 failed=0

Tags: elasticsearch

When performing updates to existing elasticsearch documents, I sometimes get a `_shards` result output where successful, total, and failed counts are all 0. Most of the time, it goes through.

How should I interpret this -- connection timeout, node temporary available? And how should I work around it? (simply try again?)

I suspect this is due to an incompatible use of some of the connection parameters with my single ES docker container development setup, but hopefully this should be a supported use case.

E.g.: update result:

```
{'_shards': {'successful': 0, 'total': 0, 'failed': 0}, 
 '_version': 2, 
 '_type': 'foo', '_index': 'foo_v1', '_id': 'AWO25xdEbiEvQ_s5I_35'
}
```

I am connecting to a single ES docker container running on the same host as the client. My ES connection parameters are the following, and I'm using them with the python elasticsearch client:

```
"es": {
    "hosts": ("http://localhost:9200",),
    "http_auth": None,
    "password": None,
    "use_ssl": False,
    "verify_certs": True,
    "sniff_on_start": True,
    "sniff_on_connection_fail": True,
    "sniffer_timeout": 60
},
```

Example update request:

```
update_res = es.update("foo_v1", doc_type="foo", id=the_id, body=patch_data)
```

This is on Elasticsearch 2.4

Answer (score 1):

The response you're receiving is what you should expect if Elasticsearch has determined that your update would not actually result in a change to the document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-update.html#_detecting_noop_updates

To verify that this is what is happening you can add the `detect_noop: false` option to your updates, which will force the server to always reindex the document even if your update doesn't actually change anything. Verify that that you don't get your 0/0/0 results any more, enjoy your increased confidence that everything's working normally, and then take the `detect_noop` option back out so that you don't do unnecessary reindexing. :)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I have incorrectly applied the rule for index to updates: "The index operation is successful in the case `successful` is at least 1." As described in [ES Index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html). The [ES Update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) docs do describe 0,0,0 as a noop. I thought `total==0` meant the request hadn't reached any shard, and so I started looking into connection problems.